# Avoiding the error where a module and a type definition occur in two parts of an assembly

Tags: f#

Suppose I have a project like this:

```ml
// Types.fs

namespace App

type Foo =
  {
    X : int
  }
```

```ml
// Foo.fs

module App.Foo

let doubleIt (foo : Foo) =
  {
    X = foo.X * 2
  }
```

Then I get an error like this:

> Types.fs(3,6): error FS0250: A module and a type definition named 'Foo' occur in namespace 'App' in two parts of this assembly

However, if I put everything in one file it works:

```ml
// Everything.fs

namespace App

type Foo =
  {
    X : int
  }

module Foo =

  let doubleIt (foo : Foo) =
    {
      X = foo.X * 2
    }
```

But to me these seem like the same thing; and I don't want to organize everything into one big file.

- What's going on here?
- Why can't I put the module into another file?
- What is an idiomatic way to organize this code?

---

```sh
dotnet --version
3.1.403
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[[FS0250] - 'ModuleSuffix' needs to be added explicitly](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/9868)

So, if you want to keep the type and module in separate files, then decorate the module name with

```
[<CompilationRepresentation(CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix)>]
```

If you place them in the same file, that gets done for you.